# Single vs. multiple MSI files in an installer

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

When creating an installer using Windows Installer (via WiX), is there any guideline as to whether or not to use a single MSI or multiple? Our application is divided into logical components internally, so I am wondering if there are any advantages to creating multiple MSI files versus a single file? We are using burn to create a bootstrapper, so I don't believe there will be any noticeable difference to the end user (but my knowledge of WiX is limited at this point). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT all depends on the size and complexity of your application.  If it's a relatively small installer with no reuse across multiple products and you are using major upgrades then one install is probably a good choice.   (KISS)

But if you have reusable pieces shipped by multiple applications  and/or you are trying to keep each installer simple so you can manage minor upgrades and patches easier then chunking it out into multiple msi's and chaining them together might be a better approach.

WiX used to have a single MSI but went to multiple MSIs.  Personally I don't see why they felt the need to do this as their footprint really isn't that big and they have never released a minor upgrade or patch.  I'm guessing they just wanted to dog food Burn with a cool looking bootstrapper application and a bunch of MSIs to chain.